# Distortion/Water in WebGL

Tags: webgl, distortion

I'm relatively new to WebGL, and OpenGL too for that matter, but in recent days I've filled up most my time writing a little game for it. However, when I wanted to implement something like heat waves, or any sort of distortion, I was left stuck.

Now, I can make a texture ripple using the fragment shader, but I feel like I'm missing something when it comes to distorting the content behind an object. Is there any way to grab the color of a pixel that's already been rendered within the fragment shader?

I've tried rendering to a texture and then having the texture of the object be that, but it appears if you choose to render your scene to a texture, you cannot render it to the screen also. And beyond that, if you want to render to a texture, that texture must be a power of two (which many screen resolutions do not quite fit into)

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to render to a texture and draw that texture onto the screen while distorting it. Also, there's no requirement that framebuffer objects must be of a power-of-two size in OpenGL ES 2.0 (which is the graphics API WebGL uses). But non-power-of-two textures can't have mipmapping or texture-wrapping.

Comment: Hm, I don't suppose there's a way to just draw the framebuffer that I've drawn the rest of the elements to to the screen, is there? I mean, right now I assume I just have to make a square with the framebuffer as a texture on it in order for it to be rendered. But if there's some way I can just take the framebuffer and directly apply it to the screen that' would be a better.

Comment: No, you're going to have to manually draw it on the screen with a textured quad. But wasn't the whole point of the exercise to distort it anyway?

Comment: Well yes and no. I'm trying to distort only very small areas. (i.e. distortion above a fire) so there's no need to distort the whole screen.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can [modify individual canvas pixels directly](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTML/Canvas/Pixel_manipulation_with_canvas). Might be a good way to ripple a small area, but might not be gpu-accelerated.